# docker system prune not clearing image older than certain time

Tags: docker

I was trying to learn how to use the filter functionality on `docker system prune`.

The following images I have

```
$ docker image ls
REPOSITORY          TAG                 IMAGE ID     CREATED              SIZE
<none>              <none>              956893e8c143        About a minute ago   114MB 
debian              stable              e1aa81b5fcf3        34 hours ago         114MB 
hello-world         latest              fce289e99eb9        14 months ago        1.84kB
```

The first one comes from this small Dockerfile:

```
FROM debian:stable

WORKDIR /var/www

RUN touch /var/www/test.txt
```

So I saw the debian image and thought I'd use that for testing:

```
$ docker system prune -af --filter "until=32h"
Deleted Images:
untagged: debian:stable
untagged: debian@sha256:fb1aa7d1aa7705388d0c8b4d8e83fdc5352b7ee13b7b7ed22ed8f45b8df3c90a

Total reclaimed space: 0B


$ docker image ls
REPOSITORY          TAG                 IMAGE ID            CREATED             SIZE
<none>              <none>              8196cdddc77e        34 seconds ago      114MB
hello-world         latest              fce289e99eb9        14 months ago       1.84kB
```

However, the "hello-world" image is still there. It's older than the timestamp I provided, so I would expect it to also have been deleted.

If I do this, it works:

```
$ docker system prune -af --filter "until=1m"
Deleted Containers:
d6e08cfd35dc370b844178b6bebea949c502de1151ea864827e8a61b7b1b9f07

Deleted Images:
untagged: hello-world:latest
untagged: hello-world@sha256:fc6a51919cfeb2e6763f62b6d9e8815acbf7cd2e476ea353743570610737b752
deleted: sha256:fce289e99eb9bca977dae136fbe2a82b6b7d4c372474c9235adc1741675f587e
deleted: sha256:af0b15c8625bb1938f1d7b17081031f649fd14e6b233688eea3c5483994a66a3
deleted: sha256:8196cdddc77eca258b8e39c178f93f303a9dfba81a03d8539cfa58e7ea8159e6
deleted: sha256:e8dac6807e18ff53265bbd3e10da48fb55b94b257ccd4c2d44cd4405babd8fdd
deleted: sha256:2608de64a55e50bee536f6b109269077b755b6d336400280f856f2f0ae65ba96
deleted: sha256:9403b1f7b97b1121829d52dc2977407c5abc19f768db793024696944824d4a99
deleted: sha256:e1aa81b5fcf33cf5e56f532b03ec4193aafee2e397029a52cd23b49a2501da64
deleted: sha256:8c0824f579db74ce6b31cc2ed9cde39f685cb4d78873205cee7596bf399c58f1

Total reclaimed space: 114.1MB

$ docker image ls
REPOSITORY          TAG                 IMAGE ID            CREATED             SIZE
```

Why did the first command not clean that older image?

And am I right in think "until" means "older than"?

Comment: From the doc: until (<timestamp>) - only remove containers, images, and networks created before given timestamp. So yes: it means the opposite.

Answer (score 1):

You're right about the meaning of `until`.

About your specific use case, the image `hello-world` was not deleted probably because there was a (not running) container using it.
That container was probably a recent one as it was deleted when you deleted everything older than **one minute** (`until=1m`).

**Why do I think that ?**
Because of this particular log on your second attempt:

```
Deleted Containers:
d6e08cfd35dc370b844178b6bebea949c502de1151ea864827e8a61b7b1b9f07
```

At this point you only had one tagged image `hello-world:latest` as show by your result of the previous `docker image ls` command.

Also you can see that after container deletion, your image is succesfully deleted.